# Xcode complains "attribute private can only be used in a non local scope" when I tried to add private in front of a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, private

When I tried to add private in front of a function, the xcode complains that "attribute private can only be used in a non local scope". I thought "private" is suppose to be used for things that you want to keep local right?

Could someone tell me how to get ride of the error message? I still want to keep the function private.

[image]

Comment: Are you declaring this function inside of another function?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm declaring it inside a function with internal access level... I guess this is what is wrong with it

Comment: Functions declared inside of another function can already only be seen inside that function, so making it private wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 25):

I made it here from searching for this error `attribute private can only be used in a non local scope`. In my case it was caused by a missing closing bracket at the end of a switch statement. Hope this helps someone.